# Can't create docker swarm service

Tags: docker, docker-machine, docker-swarm

I am new to swarm, and I am trying to get a simple service set up locally. I have set up a swarm with consul like this:

```
docker-machine create -d virtualbox consul
eval $(docker-machine env consul)
docker run -d -p 8500:8500 -h consul progrium/consul -server -bootstrap
docker-machine create -d virtualbox --swarm --swarm-master --swarm-discovery="consul://$(docker-machine ip consul):8500" --engine-opt="cluster-store=consul://$(docker-machine ip consul):8500" --engine-opt="cluster-advertise=eth1:2376" swarm-master
docker-machine create -d virtualbox --swarm  --swarm-discovery="consul://$(docker-machine ip consul):8500" --engine-opt="cluster-store=consul://$(docker-machine ip consul):8500" --engine-opt="cluster-advertise=eth1:2376" swarm-worker
eval $(docker-machine env --swarm swarm-master)
```

Everything seems fine, and `docker info` gives me:

```
Nodes: 2
swarm-master: 192.168.99.115:2376
└ ID: XRXA:2QIV:OZFX:4K3N:UF37:OWTO:TV4X:5SSE:QBGI:WDX2:ZLQS:QD7Q
└ Status: Healthy
└ Containers: 2 (2 Running, 0 Paused, 0 Stopped)
└ Reserved CPUs: 0 / 1
└ Reserved Memory: 0 B / 1.021 GiB
└ Labels: kernelversion=4.4.17-boot2docker, operatingsystem=Boot2Docker 1.12.1 (TCL 7.2); HEAD : ef7d0b4 - Thu Aug 18 21:18:06 UTC 2016, provider=virtualbox, storagedriver=aufs
└ UpdatedAt: 2016-08-29T21:10:51Z
└ ServerVersion: 1.12.1
swarm-worker: 192.168.99.116:2376
└ ID: BLNZ:TUGW:T4QQ:AUWZ:J7U3:JJTR:GHN2:SLCU:ZGRL:JGMM:LVOI:32DK
└ Status: Healthy
└ Containers: 1 (1 Running, 0 Paused, 0 Stopped)
└ Reserved CPUs: 0 / 1
└ Reserved Memory: 0 B / 1.021 GiB
└ Labels: kernelversion=4.4.17-boot2docker, operatingsystem=Boot2Docker 1.12.1 (TCL 7.2); HEAD : ef7d0b4 - Thu Aug 18 21:18:06 UTC 2016, provider=virtualbox, storagedriver=aufs
└ UpdatedAt: 2016-08-29T21:10:43Z
└ ServerVersion: 1.12.1
```

I can also create a network overlay:

```
docker network create --driver overlay my-network
docker network ls
NETWORK ID NAME DRIVER SCOPE
809a82c5c70d my-network overlay global
```

However, service creation will not work:

```
docker service create --replicas 1 --name my-web --network my-network nginx
Error response from daemon: 404 page not found
```

I have tried this on both the latest stable version (1.12.0) and the latest beta version (1.12.1-beta24) of docker engine with the same result. What is going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing up the older Docker Swarm technology setup and `docker service` which is part of the newer "Swarm Mode" technology released this past June. I really wish Docker wouldn't have used the same name for what are really two different clustering technologies.

I suggest you follow this tutorial instead. https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/swarm-tutorial/ Consul is not needed anymore. Also when you google, make sure you search for "swarm mode". It's easy to get confused with the older stuff.

Comment: Oh wow, yeah I see that I was very confused. Thanks for your help!